# ForbiddenAttributesError with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I 've just started working on ROR.
I made blog app following strictly ROR official doc.
It worked fine for CRDU.
Now I added Active Admin to it, it works fine on delete but gives error while creatiing/updating focusing on 
raise ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

```
def sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes)
    if attributes.respond_to?(:permitted?) && !attributes.permitted?
      **raise ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError**
    else
      attributes
    end
```

In Controller, I'm using following code:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to articles_path
end

private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :AuthorAge)
  end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you didn't add `permit_params` in your active admin file.

```
# app/admin/xyz.rb
permit_params :comma separated attributes.
```

Look into [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md) link for more detail.